# IllegalStateException in retryWhen with ReadStreamAdapter

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java, vert.x

I´m using `retryWhen` when a external http request to one of my external services fails. 
The problem is that I´m using

```
  RxHelper.toObservable(httpClient.request(method, url))
```

To get my observable response, and becuase vertx internally use ReadStreamAdapter I cannot use the retryWhen because it´s complain

```
 java java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request already complete
```

Here a code example:

```
  RxHelper.toObservable(httpClient.request(method, url))
  .retryWhen(new ServiceExceptionRetry())       
  .subscribe(f -> replySuccess(eventMsg, event, f), t -> handleError(t, eventMsg, event));
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `defer` to create an Observable from `method` and `client` every time like this:

```
 Observable.defer(() -> RxHelper.toObservable(httpClient.request(method, url)))
  .retryWhen(new ServiceExceptionRetry())       
  .subscribe(f -> replySuccess(eventMsg, event, f), t -> handleError(t, eventMsg, event));
```